# Como criar uma página de login com registro?

Tags: cakephp

Estou a criar uma aplicação web em cakephp e estou com dúvidas pois não estou a conseguir criar o botão registo na página de login.

Meu código é este no `\View\Users\login.ctp`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-content">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('logo1.png', array('alt' => 'fivassist Logo')); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h2>Bem-vindo!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>E-mail:</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', 
                        array('label' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
                </li>
                <li><label>Password:</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', 
                        array('label' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end login-form -->
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('id' => 'login-bt')); ?>
        <a href="#" id="forgot">Esqueceu-se da sua password?</a>

            <a href="">Regista-te</a>

    </div> <!-- end login-content -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Já tentei desta forma e não consigo meter a dar o `add.ctp` do *user*.

Answer (score 1):

Muda esta linha:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('id' => 'login-bt')); ?>
```

Para:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login', array('id' => 'login-bt')); ?>
```

O método `end` cria o submit button com as propriedades definidas no array, e adiciona a tag `</form>` no final.

E também aqui:

```
    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', 
                array('label' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
```

Você pode fazer simplesmente isto:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', 
                array('label' => 'E-mail:', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
```